# html() is not populating HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is driving me crazy. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my HTML template.

```
<template id="note-template">
    <div class="trip-note">
    </div>
    <div class="trip-note-footer">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <span class="note-author"></span>
                &bull;
                <span class="note-date"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img class="edit-note" src="~/images/tteditnote.png" title="Edit Note">
                <img class="delete-note" src="~/images/ttdeletenote.png" title="Delete Note">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And here's my JavaScript.

```
var $container = $('#trip-notes');
var $template = $('#note-template');
$container.empty();
response.forEach(function (element) {
    var $note = $($template.html());
    $note.find('.trip-note').html(element.html);
    $note.find('.note-author').text(element.author);
    $note.find('.note-date').text(element.createDate);
    $container.append($note);
});
```

Everything works exactly as expected except that my `div.trip-note` does not get set to the value in `element.html`.

`author` and `createDate` are set just fine. I've confirmed `element.html` contains the expected markup. I've retyped the class name several times (both in markup and in JavaScript). I tried mixing and matching `html()` and `text()` and the result is always the same: All elements are populated except for `div.trip-note`.

I'm either missing something very stupid or there is a peculiar issue going on.

**Update**

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcupw4hk/3/).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: `.find()` only searches for descendants. `.trip-note` is a top-level element in `$note`, not a descendant.

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find()` searches for descendants, it won't find the top-level element that you're searching from. Since `.trip-note` is one of the top-level elements of `$note`, it's note selected.

Instead of using `$template.html()`, make a clone of `$template`. Then everything will be a descendant. You can use `.html()` when you're appending to `$container` to exclude the `<template>` top-level element.

```js
var $container = $('#trip-notes');
var $template = $('#note-template');
$container.empty();
response.forEach(function (element) {
    var $note = $template.clone();
    $note.find('.trip-note').html(element.html);
    $note.find('.note-author').text(element.author);
    $note.find('.note-date').text(element.createDate);
    $container.append($note.html());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand that about `find()`. However, your code doesn't populate anything for me. Something isn't quite right.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] so I can try to debug my answer?

Comment: @Barmer: I've added a jsFiddle to my question.

Comment: @Barmer: The reason your code is not working for me is because my template uses the `<template>` tag. When you `.clone()` a template, it appears you cannot use jQuery to modify it in any way. If I change it to a `<div>` tag, it works fine. But I want to use a `<template>` tag.

Comment: Since you answered the question about why my original code was not working, perhaps I'll go ahead and accept your answer and then post a new question.

Comment: I can't find any documentation that mentions your claim that you can't modify a cloned template. And I see answers to other questions that suggest cloning a template, and they were accepted with no such qualifications.

Comment: I posted a jsfiddle. Try it for yourself. I can clone the template and add it to the DOM as you recommended. And I can edit the element that was added. But nothing I do will modify the cloned template in memory. If you have another explanation, I'm all ears.

Comment: You're right. Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27947557/1491895) that says "clone does not "see" the content of a `<template>`, due to the special nature of that particular element"